# Grok - Parse logs with lines of different lengths

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log with the following format

```
<timestamp1> <user1>-<jobclass1> <n> <user2>-<jobclass2> <n> <user3>-<jobclass3> <n> ...
<timestamp2> <user1>-<jobclass1> <n> <user2>-<jobclass2> <n> ...    
<timestamp1> <user1>-<jobclass1> <n> <user2>-<jobclass2> <n> <user3>-<jobclass3> <n> <user4>-<jobclass4> <n>...
```

And need a return like this for each user

{
  "username": [
    "XXXX"
  ],
  "jobclass": [
    "YYYY"
  ],
  "quantity": [
    "ZZZZ"
  ]
}

I try using this

%{SYSLOGBASE} %{WORD:user}-%{WORD:jobclass} %{NUMBER:quantity}

The problem is that each single line could have 4, 5, 10, 100 users. So i need to implement some kind of recursivity

Some ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi mate,

I'm asking the same thing in elastic forums here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-and-count-indeterminate-number-of-not-known-keywords/175705

I got a short answer from Badger there, for which he tells me to use "dissect", "kv" and a "ruby" filter. I think it could help you sort this out.